# Исчезают подсказки с аннотациями в Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2020

Tags: java, macos

Сразу скажу, что пользуюсь macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (последняя версия на текущий момент). На днях установил себе Ultimate версию Intellij IDEA для изучения хибернейта и спринга, а до этого пользовался CE. На CE все было в полном порядке, проблем замечено не было от слова совсем. Ни разу, за целый год программирования.
И вот, начал я пользоваться Ultimate версией. И тут же столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Начинаю писать аннотацию, например, @Entity. И, по идее, после того, как я напечатаю первую букву, у меня должен высветиться список всех аннотаций на эту букву. Ну вы знаете. И так далее, чем больше букв печатаю, тем меньше должен быть список с предложениями. Но проблема в том, что, через раз (почти всегда, но не всегда) после того, как я напечатаю первую букву, список покажется на долю секунды, и исчезнет. И мне останется только писать аннотацию целиком. Даже удаление аннотации и ее повторное пропечатывание результата никакого не даст. Произойдет то же самое - список с предложенными аннотациями исчезнет после первой же напечатанной буквы.

Как решить эту проблему, я не знаю. Я уже и удалял идею, потом чистил (на всякий случай) от кэша и временных файлов, которые оставались после идеи, и перезагружал мак, и программы, которые могли бы в теории как-то мешать вводу с клавиатуры, поотключал. Потом устанавливал идею заново. И пиратского софта на моем маке нет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, встречался ли кто-нибудь с этим?
Еще скажу, что у меня установлены несколько HomeBrew. iterm, htop, и однажды я пытался установить переводчик в командную строку, translate-shell. Что-то пошло не так, установить не удалось. Это для информации, вдруг поможет кому-то.
Спасибо всем за внимание.

Comment: Почему вы пишите сюда, а не в поддержку JetBrains? Тем более, что поддержка входит в стоимость ultimate версии.

Comment: Не понимаю, как пометить ответ как решенный. И поблагодарить за ответ.

Comment: Это не ответ, просто комментарий, его поменить решением нельзя. Да и не надо, это мелочь )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня была такая проблема , Lombok в основном тупил , подсказки тоже пропадали , откатил , на 2020.1.4 , все без проблем работает

Comment: Я тоже решил-таки откатиться, и проблема ушла. И да, у меня тоже был установлен Lombok. Видимо, проблема в нем... В гугле тоже натыкался на проблемы, связанные с ломбок и 2020.2. Спасибо за ответ.